# rails nested model query

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to work out how to use active record to return some data based on a nested model.

My relationship is setup as below:

- User - Has many books
- Book - Has many users
- UserBook - belongs to user and belongs to book

I can access users through books like so:

- book.users.first
- book.users.second

etc.

I'd like to select all the books, that does not have a particular user.

I have generated a query like this, please note, the 'near', method is provided by the Geocoder gem.

```
Book.near(location, distance).joins(:users).where("users.id != #{@current_user.id}")
```

I believe the syntax is correct, no errors occur, however, the query still returns books with the current user.

The issue appears to be that if book.users contains a user id that is not current user id AND also contains the current user id, book is still returned.

I can get the desired result using code like this, but I presume there is a way to get ActiveRecord to do it for me.

```
search = Book.near(location, distance).reject do |book|
    if book.users.include?(@current_user)
        book
    end
end
```

Comment: `"users.id != {@current_user.id}"` is that a typo?

Comment: no...is there a problem with that syntax?

Comment: Should be `"users.id != #{@current_user.id}"` if you want to interpolate `@current_user.id`

Comment: yes that was a typo, fixed the question and added some more info.